# How to enable/disable ffimageloading transformations in xaml/mvvm? [Xamarin forms]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have images in a listview and to start it off I grayscale them all.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Image}" x:Name = "Images">
       <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations  >                     
            <fftransformations:GrayscaleTransformation/>
            <fftransformations:CircleTransformation/>
      </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
 </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

<Button Command="{Binding ImageClick}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference Images}" BorderRadius="7" />
```

In my mainviewmodel i have a command.

```
this.ImageClick = new Command(ClickedEvent);
```

And here i know what image that was clicked, how can i now disable grayscale on that particular image? Without disabling the circular transformation.

```
void ClickedEvent (object sender)
{
    var clickedImage = sender as CachedImage;
    var rowData = clickedImage.BindingContext as MyClass;
    // Now i am unsure on how to proceed
}

public class MyClass
{
     public string Image {get;set;}
     public bool GrayScaleVisibility {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bindings to transformations, and update them as you want.

Example:

```
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            LoadingPlaceholder="loading.png" ErrorPlaceholder="error.png" DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400"
            Transformations="{Binding Transformations}" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

And the ViewModel from the Documentation- 
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/Transformations/TransformationsSelectorPageModel.cs